# Limitations of C++20 abbreviated function templates

Tags: c++, templates

This is OK:

```
template<typename T> void test1(T x) {}
void abbreviated_test1(auto x) {} // equivalent to above
```

But this is not:

```
template <typename T> struct matrix {};
template<typename T> void test2(matrix<T> x) {}
// try abbreviated form:
void abbreviated_test2(matrix<auto> x) {} // error: 'auto' not allowed in template argument
```

Is there a reason why? Are there plans to support more complex abbreviated function templates in the future?

Comment: "*Are there plans to support more complex abbreviated function templates in the future?*" I seriously doubt it. The reason why it is not supported is that it was rejected by the committee, but the relevant details may need to look through historical documents.